# Clear a Specific Slicer on the Active Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have have two slicers on a worksheet.  One is named Region, the other is named Hospital.  I am trying to create two buttons on the page.  One that will clear ONLY the Hospital slicer; the other to clear ONLY the Region slicer on the active worksheet only.  I have a button that will clear ALL of the slicers on the active worksheet (code below), but I am struggling to get it to work only with the specific slicer.

```
Sub ClearSlicer()

'
'Clears Slicer on main dashboard page
'

Dim Slcr As SlicerCache
Dim slc As Slicer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Slcr In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    For Each slc In Slcr.Slicers
        If slc.Shape.Parent Is ActiveSheet Then
           Slcr.ClearManualFilter
           Exit For
        End If
    Next slc
Next Slcr

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have tried adding 
`ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Hospital")`
but this did not seem to work either.  This threw a debug error which I was not able to correct.

I have searched and yet to find this on here, so I apologize if I happened to miss it.  Any assistance here would be helpful.  Thank you

Comment: I don't know in your language, but in my language if your slicer is called "Hospital" the `Slcr.Name` will return something like "SlicerCache_Hospital". Use `If Slcr.Name Like "*Hospital" Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to a `Slicer` by [`.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.slicer.name):

```
Sub ClearSlicer()

'
'Clears Slicer on main dashboard page
'

Dim Slcr As SlicerCache
Dim slc As Slicer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Slcr In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    For Each slc In Slcr.Slicers
        If slc.Name = "Region" Or slc.Name = "Hospital" Then
            Slcr.ClearManualFilter
        End If
    Next slc
Next Slcr

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you're not exactly sure on the slicer name, perhaps use `Like`:

```
If slc.Name Like "*Region*" Or slc.Name Like "*Hospital*" Then
```

(though you might then need to check whether the slicer is on the `ActiveSheet` as you currently do).

Comment: Hi BigBen... a couple of things. Slicers have a name with a prefix, also if the slicer is the one he wants is already on the sheet, so there is no need to check both name and sheet, just the one name. I mean, you can have 2 slicers for the Hospital, but the second one will be SlicerCache_Hospital1 so there is no point on checking the sheet.

Comment: @Damian - my slicers did not have a prefix. The point about activesheet is good though. In any case yes `Like` might be a good idea (well then you might need to consider the `ActiveSheet`, if another sheet has a hospital or region slicer).

Comment: Right... then that must be my office version... weird thing

Comment: @Damian could `SlicerCache_Hospital1` be the name for the `SlicerCache` object, while the `Slicer` object's name is `Hospital`?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTbwn.png) is how it works in my version at least. `Nombre del origen:` means source name, which is `Fecha` and would be `Hospital` in this case. `Nombre para usar en las fórmulas:` means name to use on formulas is what I need to reference on vba @MathieuGuindon